# What is the function of a comma between arguments in awk?

Tags: awk

For [this](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/bash-tutorials---arithmetic-operations/) HackerRank bash challenge (round to 3 decimal places), the following solution works well:

```
$ echo '5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7' | bc -l | awk '{ printf ("%.3f \n",$1) }'
17.929
```

whereas the same without a comma between printf's format string and the $1 produces the following error on a bash prompt:

```
$ echo '5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7' | bc -l | awk '{ printf ("%.3f \n" $1) }'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
        `%.3f
17.92857142857142857142'
           ^ ran out for this one
```

The error message suggests that the $1 without comma is not supplied as an argument to printf, but its elision has hitherto not caused me issues (`awk '{ print $0 " with appendix." }'` happily prints the appended text). Understandably, searching [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) for values separated by commas is not helpful. What is the function of the comma in separating arguments in awk (aside from inserting a space between strings)? Additionally: what are the round brackets doing in the example? For what it's worth, HackerRank gives the following error:

```
bc -l | awk '{ printf ("%.3f \n" $1) }'
```

```
Your Output (stdout)
0.000 
17.92857142857142857142
```

Comment: It's the same as the `,` between arguments in any function call in any language. See the awk man page. You don't need `bc` when you're using `awk`.

Comment: They are two different commands. `printf` takes a format argument and zero or more string arguments, each separated by commas which act simply as delimiters. `print` takes zero or more string arguments. If they aren't separated by commas then they are concatenated. If separated by commas, the output consists of the strings concatenated with a space between each.

Comment: interesting thing about `s/printf( )` : `awk 'BEGIN { printf(_) }'` is perfectly valid syntax, despite only one single empty formatting string being passed in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't even need `awk` to restrict decimal number to 3 decimal points. `bc` itself can do that:

```bash
bc -l <<< 'scale=3; 5+50*3/20 + (19*2)/7'

17.928
```

Now question about `printf`, [syntax of `printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Basic-Printf.html) should be:

```bash
printf format, item1, item2, …
```

But when you use it like this:

```bash
printf ("%.3f \n" $1)
```

You don't supply enough number of arguments to satisfy `%.3f` format string (since `"%.3f \n"` and `$1` are concatenated into a single string), hence you get this error:

```bash
not enough arguments to satisfy format string
```

Even if you put parentheses around, it doesn't make error go away. `(...)` is optional in `printf` so it can be either of these 2 statements:

```bash
printf "%.3f \n", $1
printf ("%.3f \n", $1)
```

Answer (score 2):

awk does not have an explicit string concatenation operator. Two strings are concatenated by simply placing then side-by-side

```
print "foo" "bar"   # => prints "foobar"
```

When you omit the comma, you have essentially this:

```
fmt = "%.3f \n" $1   # the string => "%.3f\n17.92"
printf (fmt)
```

and theres a %f directive but no value given.

Answer (score 1):

> The error message suggests that the $1 without comma is not supplied as an argument to printf, but its elision has hitherto not caused me issues (`awk '{ print $0 " with appendix." }'` happily prints the appended text)

Yes.  Both effects arise from the fact that `awk` concatenates adjacent strings without any explicit operator.  And not only literals.  See [section 6.2.2](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Concatenation) of the manual for details and examples.  In the case of your `print` statement, that produces an effect that serves your purpose, but in the case of your `printf` call, it means that you are passing only one, concatenated argument to `printf`, which it interprets as a format string.

When you put a comma between the strings, whether in a `print` statement or in a `printf` call, you get a list of two items instead of a single, concatenated string.

Comment: Had I enough reputation to vote, I'd definitely give you a bump up for the link to the relevant section of the docs, which starts with the amusing quote from Brian Kernighan re implicit string concatenation, "It seemed like a good idea at the time."

Comment: Yes, @ARMs_for_the_poor, I was amused by that too. I also observe that C (another Kernighan project) has similar concatentation behavior, but only for string literals.

Comment: i think this string concat flexibility is a big plus 4 `awk` ::::::::: ::::::: ::::::::::: :::::::::: ::::::::: ::::::::: `mawk 'BEGIN { OFMT = "%.250g" } { print _="", __=$++_, +__,__^++_,_=$_,_*_, _=(__)_,+_ }' <<< '0xAADEF 78954321'` ::::::::::: `0xAADEF 699887 489841812769 78954321 6233784804571041 0xAADEF78954321 3005993798943521` : how many langs u know of that can take in 2 string parts 1 hex 1 decimal integer, decode them to ints, square them both, **and** also decode out a different int resulting from interpreting a new concatenated hex `$1 $2`, all within that tiny amount of code ?